# Permission for IAM user to create lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Thanks in advance for any help!

So, as a root user, I am able to setup IAM roles and use it to create and running lambda functions. However, I want users in my organizations to be able to do the same. So I setup some IAM users and assigned them the following permissions:

[image]
But when I logged in to AWS as an IAM user, it seems I can't do much about creating roles/policies etc. (which are needed to create lambda function). I get the following error:

> User: arn:aws:iam:::user/xxxxx is not authorized to perform: iam:GetAccountSummary on resource.

But I give the user IAMFullAccess. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Could you please check whether this is the full error message? Normally, it would say _which_ resource is being denied.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, be very careful about assigning users "Full" access to services.

From these permissions you have assigned, your users would be able to:

- Delete all RDS databases
- Terminate all EC2 instances
- Delete all CodeCommit repositories
- Delete all Lambda functions
- Delete all IAM Users (including *your* login!)
- Grant themselves permission to do *anything* on your AWS account!

The best-practice method would be for a Systems Administrator to create the IAM Role for use by a Lambda function, after reviewing it to confirm that it does not give excessive permission. They would then grant permission for particular users to be able to assign the Role to a Lambda function. I see no reason for assigning them all those permissions (eg RDS, EC2) just to write a Lambda function.

Secondly, if you wish to assign permissions to multiple IAM Users, it is better to assign the permissions to an **IAM Group**, and then associate the group with each user. This way, you can adjust permissions in one location rather than having to do it on each user individually.

As to why you are receiving the error, it is possible that there is a restriction on your account through an **AWS Organizations** rule on a higher-level account. Otherwise, it seems that you have assigned quite generous permissions and should not be receiving this error.

Comment: John, you did not answer the question